# How to debug UnsupportedOperationException happening for Cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview randomly

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk-project

We have developed a hybrid mobile application , Random crash of app is happining while it is in active state . Maybe the crash is happening due to the click event (randomly).

We are using Cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.3.0 and crosswalk lite version.
How to find the the root cause of the issue?

The following exception captured while app crash

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
at org.xwalk.core.ReflectMethod.invoke (ReflectMethod.java:57)
at org.xwalk.core.XWalkView.onTouchEvent (XWalkView.java:878)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent (View.java:7791)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2316)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2013)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2322)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:1985)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2322)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:1985)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2322)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:1985)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2322)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:1985)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2322)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:1985)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2322)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:1985)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent (PhoneWindow.java:2145)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent (PhoneWindow.java:1577)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent (Activity.java:2505)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent (PhoneWindow.java:2093)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent (View.java:7982)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:4384)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess (ViewRootImpl.java:4255)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3801)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:3851)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3820)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3927)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3828)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3984)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3801)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:3851)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3820)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3828)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3801)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:6116)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents (ViewRootImpl.java:6096)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:6050)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:6246)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent (InputEventReceiver.java:185)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:138)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5363)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:828)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:644)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
```